# Snap edge to vertex by dragging one side of the edge?

Tags: snapping

I would like to drag a vertex, in such a way, that the moving edge snaps to another vertex.

Below shows what I'm doing now. I drag the vertex to the right until it 'looks okay', but I really want that edge to snap to that bottom vertex above. That way the edge would be in line with the other vertices. Is that possible?

(Note this is xray view, so the moving edge doesn't actually touch those other vertices.)

[image: Dragging vertex example]